Leaves darkening, stiffening, curling up, brown spots underneath - is this Little Cherry disease?
This is a Montmorency cherry. Its leaves became darker in color, stiffer, curled up and have a lot of small brown spots underneath.
Is this Little Cherry disease?





Not sure what's wrong, but I have Montmorency, and the sour cherry is related to plum, not cherry.
